# When a homotopy equivalence of the closed unit ball in the Euclidean n- dimensional space is injective?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I have a compact connected metric space $X$ of dimension $n$ which is homotopically equivalent to the closed unit ball $D^n$ in the n-dimensional Euclidean space. I am wondering if there is an homotopy equivalence $h$ such that either $h$ or its homotopy inverse is injective.

Thank you.

Comment: Sure. The identity map or any homeomorphism. *Any* continuous  map $D^n \to D^n$ is a homotopy equivalence, so you just need to write down an example of an injective map.

Comment: @MikeMiller: I think the OP is asking whether such a map must exist for *all* such spaces $X$.

Comment: Let me suggest an equivalent rewording of the question which might be clearer: Given any compact, contractible, $n$-dimensional metric space $X$, must it happen that either $X$ embeds in $D^n$ or $D^n$ embeds in $X$?

Comment: @Lee mosher can you please tell me the meaning of n-dimensional metric space... I actually don't know anything like this... Thanks in advance

Comment: @AnubhaV: The OP should be the one to say what he means by "dimension $n$". There are many different meanings in topology.

Comment: @AnubhaV: By dimension n I mean the small inductive dimension but since $X$ is metric and separable any notion of dimension is the same.

Comment: @LeeMosher That is exactly what I want to know.

Answer (score 2):

I dont think this is atall true...since $D^n$ is contractible so any map is actually homotopic to constant map...so if you casider $X= D^n$ then for given any map $f,g: D^n \rightarrow D^n$ $fog$ and $gof$ is homotopic to constant map and thus homotopic to identity map...

Comment: I am aware of what you say, but I am looking for the existence of an homotopy equivalence which is injective. I will edit my question.